# Why am I receiving this error: QUOTA_CIRCUMVENTION

Tags: youtube-api

Google Cloud Support asked me to reach out here to get an answer as to why we're receiving an error that is shutting down our API.  The error is: QUOTA_CIRCUMVENTION

Details
Project impacted: Barrows Levy Videos (id: barrows-levy-videos)

Description: Circumventing our quota restrictions via multiple projects acting as one.

We are only using one project and have the playlist getting pulled into the website https://www.barrowslevy.com/.

How do we resolve this issue?  We've already been shut down with a previous API and we had to create a new Restricted one.  This one was also flagged.

How are we circumventing the quota?  What can we do to NOT circumvent the quota?

Comment: I find it strange that google support directed you here instead of solving your issue. They have access to your account and your project.

Comment: I found it very strange too.  In the appeal there was a support phone number.  They told me they could not support Youtube API specifically and directed me here.  Absurd and infuriating.

Comment: Thank you for contacting Google Cloud Platform Support. Just for a quick recap of our conversation you needed assistance in resolving the error message that you are receiving for using YouTube API as the error message is stating QUOTA_CIRCUMVENTION for multiple project, however you just have one project.

As we discussed on our phone session, I will be providing you with the link for you to be able to get assistance from our YouTube API support team. Kindly please go to this link for more information [1].

Best Regards,
Clio
Google Cloud Support

Comment: The link brought me to a Stack Overflow, where I had to create an account and tag "youtube-api".  Very frustrating